# Можно ли так задать массив объектов?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Не сильно понимаю, как создаётся массив объектов obj. Может кто-то объяснить? Для меня, как для новичка, это выглядит будто мы сначала создали массив obj, а потом просто превратили его в объект

```
const getNameAndSurname = users.map((element) => {
  let obj = []
  obj = {
    name: element.name,
    surname: element.surn
  }
  return obj
})
```

Comment: _сначала создали массив obj, а потом просто превратили его в объект_ - не превратили, а забыли про массив и просто присвоили объект.

Comment: Можно. Но в JS массивы - это тоже объекты) И динамическая типизация - вы создали массив (он всё равно `object`), присвоили `object` = у вас `object`. Дальше присвоите `2` - получите `number`.

Comment: по факту, запись в виде `let obj = []` в данном случае абсолютно бессмысленна, даже если там было не `[]`, а `1234` или `'hello world'`. Если основное значение присваивается ниже то и писать надо `let obj = { ...`  ..... а в текущем случае можно даже вообще без него и писать сразу `return { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Метод `map()` позволяет выполнить функцию для каждого элемента массива, а результаты выполнения возвращаются в виде нового массива.
Специально создавать массив с результатами не нужно, внутри функции обрабатывается один элемент массива.

В твоём примере: если `users` уже массив пользователей, то:

```js
const getNameAndSurname = users.map((element) => {
  return {
    name: element.name,
    surname: element.surn
  }
});
```

в результате переменная `getNameAndSurname` - будет массивом объектов, каждый из которых будет иметь поля `name` и `surname`

Если дополнительных действий в функции не нужно, то `return` тоже можно не писать, чтоб код выглядел лаконичнее:

```js
const getNameAndSurname = users.map((element) => ({
    name: element.name,
    surname: element.surn
}));
```